# Does creating a jQuery object in a function then not using it create a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

For example:

```
function getTimeFromMin(min) {
    var tempTime = new Date();
    tempTime.setHours(0, min, 0, 0);
    return angular.element('<input type="hidden"/>').timepicker('setTime', tempTime).val();
}
```

I am only getting the value but what happens to the element that was created? Does it get collected or should I delete the element and return the val() separately?

Comment: If the widget is built correctly, you can destroy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as of today is that yes, your function is likely leaking memory, but that depends on exactly what the `timepicker` function does.  I'm assuming it's a jQuery UI style widget in this answer which means that it stores an object using `jQuery.prototype.data`.

Due to garbage collection issues in older browsers, the actual object where this data is stored isn't the element itself, but a separate object.  Data is retrieved by referencing a property in that object that corresponds to an expando property on the element that is created by jQuery.  In order to avoid leaking memory, you need to call the `.remove` function on the element that you've created in order to remove the data cache in the object that I mentioned previously.

Essentially, change your code to this:

```
var tmp = angular.element('<input type="hidden"/>').timepicker('setTime', tempTime),
    val = tmp.val();

tmp.remove();
return val;
```

In future versions of jQuery ( 3.X and up ), this answer is likely to be invalid.  I believe they're considering attaching data directly to DOM elements in the future since newer browsers do not have garbage collections like older browsers do.  Alternatively, they may begin using a `WeakMap` as their object store once EcmaScript 6 had wide browser support, but don't expect that for quite a while.